# MDI-Form ignores StyleElements seClient

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i have a problem with the VCL-Styles and MDI-Form. I want to use the VCL Styles, but i also want to draw the background (image) of my MainForm (MDI) by myself. This worked fine without VCL Styles, but when a Style is active the background image of the MainForm isn't shown.

[image: Without Style]

I checked out the StyleElements for the MainForm, but exclude the seClient is ignoerd and the background image isn't shown.

[image: With Style]

When i exclude the seClient and seBoarder the image is shown again. Obviously the Form Boarder lost the Style, which is also not that what i want.

[image: Exclude seClient/seBoarder]

The image is drawn at the Canvas in the ClientWndProc by the messages WM_ERASEBKGND, WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL. With the Styles, it looks like this events didn't raise. Is there any way the get the image at the form background with VCL Styles active?

Comment: If you're using Styles you need to create a custom `TFormStyleHook` and do your painting in the `PaintNC` and `PaintBackground` methods.  [See here](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/03/26/vcl-styles-adding-background-images-and-colors-to-delphi-forms/) for an example.  That said, I've never done this - not sure if it works.  MDI and styles don't always play well together...

Comment: I tryed it with the Demo from the VCL Style Utils, and it doesn't work. The background image is drawn, but not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point to realize here is that form styled `fsMDIForm` is a very special `TWinControl` that manages **two** window handles instead of one - [`TWinControl.Handle`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_Handle.html) and [`TForm.ClientHandle`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_ClientHandle.html). While the first handle is the form window itself the second is MDI client window (container-like for MDI child windows inside MDI parent).

`TFormStyleHook` hooks both window procedures and introduces new method `TFormStyleHook.MDIClientWndProc`, which processes messages sent to MDI client. This method luckily virtual. It does some pre-processing of messages and then calls the original hooked procedure. The sad part is that it prevents calling the old procedure for `WM_NCACTIVATE`, `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_ERASEBKGND`. Even worse is that on `WM_ERASEBKGND` it paints the client area background directly using [`StyleServices`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Themes.StyleServices).

Thanks to the above the subclassing of `TFormStyleHook` for MDI forms a PITA. I see multiple design flaws here:

1. Missing virtual `TFormStyleHook.PaintMDIClientBackground` similar to `TFormStyleHook.PaintBackground`.
2. No way to control/access over the original MDI client proc without hacking (hidden in private field `FMDIPrevClientProc`).
3. Disability to control styling of MDI client window via `TForm.StyleElements` (as noted by OP).

So what is the workaround? The easiest I can see is creating a custom style hook:

```
type
  TMainFormStyleHook = class(TFormStyleHook)
  public
    procedure MDIClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

{ TMainFormStyleHook }

procedure TMainFormStyleHook.MDIClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
  begin
    { TODO: Paint background to TWMEraseBkgnd(Message).DC }
    Message.Result := 1;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

and applying it to your MDI parent:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
    { ... }
  end;

{ TMainForm }

class constructor TMainForm.Create;
begin
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TMainForm, TMainFormStyleHook);
end;

class destructor TMainForm.Destroy;
begin
  TCustomStyleEngine.UnRegisterStyleHook(TMainForm, TMainFormStyleHook);
end;
```

Note that you still need to keep painting background in MDI parent form in case the VCL styles are disabled, so it's worth creating method `TMainForm.PaintMDICLientBackground(DC: HDC)` and call it from both places.

I would argue that this is a bug in VCL. How about you guys?

Comment: I agree that this is a bug in VCL. I tryed your solution and it works so far. There is one little problem with the refresh. If i move a MDI-ClientForm over the background, it's left fragments of the form behind it. So i have to refresh it by myself, but that shouldn't be a big problem